# How to put the result of a regex match function into pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have this function:

```
def find_regex(regex, text, opzione2= None, opzione3 = None):
    lista = []
    for x in text:
        matches_prima = re.findall(regex, x)
        matches_prima2 = []
        matches_prima3 = []
        if opzione2 is not None:
            matches_prima2 = re.findall(opzione2, x)
            if opzione3 is not None:
                matches_prima3 = re.findall(opzione3, x)
        lunghezza = len(matches_prima) + len(matches_prima2) + len(matches_prima3)
        lista.append(lunghezza)

    print(sum(lista))
```

Let's say I have the text is "I love cats" and the regex is "cat", the result would be one.

I have

```
def pandas():
  regex1 = re.compile(r"cat")
  text1 = "I love cats"
  find_regex(regex1, text1) #it returns 1
  df = pd.DataFrame([find_regex(regex1, text1)])
  print(df)
```

It won't work. What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Where is `return` statement in your `find_regex` function?

Comment: I have none, is this the problem?

Comment: If you still need help please consider doing the following: 1) Provide your inputs. A string? A file? What do they look like? List of words to search for? Should they be whole words? etc. 2) What exact expected output you need. Else, we can't help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have inferred *A LOT* of things here, but I think at least it puts you in
an enhanced state with an operational code.

Text used as input:

```
Text
Be cxt careful with that cxt.
Be cat careful with that cat.
Stop waiting for the cat to just happen.
He found the cat covered with cats.
The dogmatic people who cat insist are so cathartic!
There should have been a cat and a dog.
Three people with six decades of cat experience.
```

```
import pandas as pd
import re

def find_regex(regex, text, opzione2=None, opzione3=None):
    matches_prima = re.findall(regex, text)
    lunghezza = len(matches_prima)
    if opzione2:
        matches_prima2 = re.findall(opzione2, text)
        lunghezza += len(matches_prima2)
        if opzione3:
            matches_prima3 = re.findall(opzione3, text)
            lunghezza += len(matches_prima3)
    return lunghezza

df = pd.read_csv("data.txt")
print(df)

regex1 = r"cat"
regex2 = r"dog"
regex3 = r"people"

df["CntRegex[1]"] = df["Text"].map(lambda x: find_regex(regex1, x))
df["CntRegex[1&2]"] = df["Text"].map(lambda x: find_regex(regex1, x, regex2))
df["CntRegex[1&2&3]"] = df["Text"].map(lambda x: find_regex(regex1, x, regex2, regex3))

with pd.option_context('display.max_colwidth', 25, "display.max_columns", None):
    print(df)
```

```
                       Text  CntRegex[1]  CntRegex[1&2]  CntRegex[1&2&3]
0  Be cxt careful with t...            0              0                0
1  Be cat careful with t...            2              2                2
2  Stop waiting for the ...            1              1                1
3  He found the cat cove...            2              2                2
4  The dogmatic people w...            2              3                4
5  There should have bee...            1              2                2
6  Three people with six...            1              1                2
```